# Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created a firebase function that listen on onCreate event, however the DocumentSnapshot.data() is returning empty.

The function code is:

```
exports.createClientAccount = functions.firestore
  .document('/userProfile/{userId}/clientList/{clientId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    console.log('****snap.data(): ', snap.data()); //Showing Empty from the console.
    return admin
      .auth()
      .createUser({
        uid: context.params.clientId,
        email: snap.data().email,
        password: '123456789',
        displayName: snap.data().fullName,
      })
      .then(userRecord => {
        return admin
          .database()
          .ref(`/userProfile/${userRecord.uid}`)
          .set({
            fullName: userRecord.displayName, //ERROR here: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined
            email: userRecord.email,
            coachId: context.params.userId,
            admin: false,
            startingWeight: snap.data().startingWeight,
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('****Error creating new user',error);
      });
  });
```

The document IS created on the firebase database under

```
/userProfile/{userId}/clientList/{clientId}
```

[clientId document created on the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byaAd.png)

As per the documentation, onCreate listens when a new document is created and returns the snapshot of the data created through the DocumentSnapshot interface. However, I have checked from the console that snap.data() is empty. I don't understand why it is empty if the document is created successfully on the database.

[image showing error returned by the functions when creating the userProfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0gck.png)

From the function code, `return admin.auth.createUser({})` is creating the user as anonymous because snap.data().email is undefined, but it should create a non anonymous user.

Answer (score 0):

First, please try to change `document('/userProfile/{userId}/clientList/{clientId}')` to `document('userProfile/{userId}/clientList/{clientId}')`.

`path` should not start with `/`.

```
exports.createClientAccount = functions.firestore
  .document('userProfile/{userId}/clientList/{clientId}')
```

Comment: Hi @zkohi Thanks for the help! At the end problem was that when I created the document with add({}) I was not including the fields in the instruction. This is the function that creates the client document and now the function gets triggered correctly
async clientCreate(
    fullName: string,
    email: string,
    startingWeight: number
  ): Promise<any> {
    const newClientRef = await this.firestore
      .collection(`userProfile/${this.userId}/clientList/`)
      .add({
        fullName, 
        email, 
        startingWeight: startingWeight * 1, 
      });

Comment: Hi @Jorge Willian Alvarado Jiménez thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

At the end problem was that when I created the document with add({}) I was not including the fields in the instruction. This is the function that creates the client document and now the function gets triggered correctly.

```
  async clientCreate(
    fullName: string,
    email: string,
    startingWeight: number
  ): Promise<any> {
    const newClientRef = await this.firestore
      .collection(`userProfile/${this.userId}/clientList/`)
      .add({
        fullName,
        email, 
        startingWeight: startingWeight * 1,
      });

    return newClientRef.update({
      id: newClientRef.id
    }); 
}
```

I was calling `this.firestore.collection(...).add({})` with no fields, so when it happened, the cloud function got triggered and the `DocumentSnapshot.data()` was empty thus returning the `Reference.set` error. The cloud function `createClientAccount` is correct. Thanks.